# Computing the variation $|\nu|(E)$

Tags: measure-theory

I am to find $|\nu|$ if $\nu(E) = \int_{E} f d\, \mu$, where $\mu \ge 0$, moreover $f \in L^1(\mu)$.

I know that 
$$|\nu|(E) = \sup_{P} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\nu(E_k)|, \quad \bigcup_{k \ge 1} E_k = E, \quad E_i \cap Ej = \emptyset \text{ for } i \neq j.$$
Of course $P$ are all devisions described above.

My attempt
$$|\nu|(E) = \sup_{P} \sum_{k \ge 1} |\nu(E_k)| = \sup_{P} \sum_{k \ge 1} \left|\int_{E_k} f d\mu \right| \\
\ge \sup_{P} \sum_{k \ge 1} \int_{E_k} \left| f \right| d\mu \ge \left| \left| f \right| \right|_{L^1} \sum_{k \ge 1} = \infty.$$

Thus $|\nu|(E) = \infty$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\nu|(E) = \sup_P \sum_{k \ge 1} |\nu(E_k)|
= \sup_P \sum_{k \ge 1} \left|\int_{E_k} f \, d\mu\right|
\le \sup_P \sum_{k\ge1} \int_{E_k} |f| \, d\mu
= \int_E |f| \, d\mu.$$
To show equality, find a partition $P$ that makes the inequality tight.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out what should the partition look like.